# Typewriter effect text animation

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a typewriter animation effect with a UILabel, but can't find any answers. Is the UILabel the correct object to use? I want the text to print to the screen an array of strings like, "Logging in...  Opening Folder... Rebooting system.." etc. I should mention that I'm new to coding and I've tried searching the Documentation and API reference but no luck. I'm currently learning SWIFT if thats worth mentioning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letter by letter animation for UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

update: **Xcode 7.0 GM • Swift 2.0**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTypeWriter: UITextField!
    let myText = Array("Hello World !!!".characters)
    var myCounter = 0
    var timer:NSTimer?
    func fireTimer(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func typeLetter(){
        if myCounter < myText.count {
            myTypeWriter.text = myTypeWriter.text! + String(myText[myCounter])
            let randomInterval = Double((arc4random_uniform(8)+1))/20
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomInterval, target: self, selector: "typeLetter", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        myCounter++
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fireTimer()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Can't wait to try this one out.

Comment: @Leo Dabus, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) 

myTypeWriter.text = myTypeWriter.text! + String(myText[myCounter])

Answer (score 16):

Based on this Answer:
[Letter by letter animation for UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel)

I've updated it to Swift 4 and solved the CPU animation problem with [DispatchWorkItem](https://medium.com/@yostane/swift-sweet-bits-the-dispatch-framework-ios-10-e34451d59a86) in order to create a queue.

**Swift 4**

```
extension UILabel {
    func setTextWithTypeAnimation(typedText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval = 5.0) {
        text = ""
        var writingTask: DispatchWorkItem?
        writingTask = DispatchWorkItem { [weak weakSelf = self] in
            for character in typedText {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    weakSelf?.text!.append(character)
                }
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: characterDelay/100)
            }
        }
        
        if let task = writingTask {
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "typespeed", qos: DispatchQoS.userInteractive)
            queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: task)
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Usage**

```
label.setTextWithTypeAnimation(typedText: text, characterDelay:  10) //less delay is faster
```

---

**Swift 5**

```swift
func setTyping(text: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval = 5.0) {
  self.text = ""
    
  let writingTask = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
    text.forEach { char in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.text?.append(char)
      }
      Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: characterDelay/100)
    }
  }
    
  let queue: DispatchQueue = .init(label: "typespeed", qos: .userInteractive)
  queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: writingTask)
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
label.setTyping(text: "Your text")
```

Comment: It does seem to do the trick, the problem is if you set a new string before the animation ends. It will smash potato the two strings together. If there was a way to cancel the task before starting a new one would be perfect.

Comment: @RyuuzakiJulio I think you can disable your string input source and make a counter inside the writing task to check whether it has ended or not. In other words, when the counter is equal to the number of characters, the input will be enabled again.

Comment: @dimas-mendes does that mean that all new inputs will be disabled until the first animation is done? So if I have a more important new text coming on, it will be ignored until the previous message is finished? Is there a way to keep the task and cancel it when a new task comes in?

Comment: @RyuuzakiJulio yes, I don't know the logic inside your app, but I think you can create a temporary structure to store all the writing tasks, and if you need to cancel, you may call "workItem?.cancel()" on each pending task.

Comment: @dimas-mendes My app reacts to bluetooth / user button press events. I have a "Status" label that displays the most current event and I thought it would be nice to have an animation. It does sound logic, to have a list of messages and display them in order. My problem with your solution is that the tasks get created inside the UILabel extension Function so once is called again, there is no record of the previous task, how would you store them somewhere to be able to cancel them before the new one comes in? I can't create an array of tasks inside UILabel Extension.

Comment: @RyuuzakiJulio UIExtensions can't store properties, but you can pass the structure as a parameter inside setTextWithTypeAnimation, right? The problem is that you need to pass the array by reference, using "inout" "allTasks: inout [DispatchWorkItem]" and then adding the value to the array using append inside the let block "allTasks.append(writingTask!)"

Answer (score 9):

I have written a subclass of UILabel called [CLTypingLabel](https://github.com/l800891/CLTypingLabel), available on GitHub. This should do what you want.

After installing CocoaPods, add the following like to your Podfile to use it:

```
pod 'CLTypingLabel'
```

### Sample Code

Change the class of a label from UILabel to CLTypingLabel;
[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTypeWriterLabel: CLTypingLabel!
```

At runtime, set text of the label will trigger animation automatically:

```
myTypeWriterLabel.text = "This is a demo of typing label animation..."
```

You can customize time interval between each character:

```
myTypeWriterLabel.charInterval = 0.08 //optional, default is 0.1
```

You can pause the typing animation at any time:

```
myTypeWriterLabel.pauseTyping() //this will pause the typing animation
myTypeWriterLabel.continueTyping() //this will continue paused typing animation
```

Also there is a sample project that comes with [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CLTypingLabel)

Comment: This is nice library but now does not supports latest iOS 16 on some of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

my version of the typewriter effect animation using a timer:

```
    var text = "text"
    
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        withTimeInterval: 0.1,
        repeats: true
    ) { [weak self] timer in
        let char = text.removeFirst()
        
        self?.yourLabel.text?.append(char.description)
        
        if text.isEmpty {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```