# Does there exists a counterpart of Java's TimerTask in Swift?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, timertask

I am using the TimerTask in an Android application. Now I want to use a similar concept in Swift.

Does there exist a counterpart of this functionality in Swift (iOS)?

Here is some sample Java code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (lastItem.contains("mynp")) {

            // Do Stuff

            // Stop the thread
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}, 0, 10);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736360/typewriter-effect-text-animation/27736913#27736913

Comment: @Mundi - what does that "duplicate" have to do with this question?

Comment: I agree. The answer for the duplicate demonstrates how to use `NSTimer`, but it is hardly an "exact duplicate".  I am sure there are dupes for this question, but probably better ones

Comment: @maddy it shows how to use an NSTimer.

Comment: @Mundi FYI - A duplicate is when both questions ask the same basic question, not just when some other question has an answer that could be relevant.

Comment: Reopened the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) I can post an objective-c example if that's helpful, but I'm not familiar with Swift yet.