# Display String one by one from array list in iOS Xcode 5

Tags: ios, c, xcode, macos

I have a chunk of string and i am taking all string in array list separate by white space and want to display in same text box one by one suppose i have a string "my name is xyz" then text box should contends data like this "my" then wait for few seconds and then display "name" and again wait and display "is" and so on.....

```
  - (IBAction)btnstart:(id)sender {

    NSString *myString=self.textcollector.text;
    NSArray *readerArray=[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    int arraylenght=[readerArray count];
    textcollector.text=@"";


    for(int i=0;i<arraylenght;i++)
    {


    //textcollector=NULL;
    self.textcollector.text=readerArray[i];
    //NSLog(@" ",readerArray[i]);
    sleep(1);
   // textcollector.a

    }
```

}

Comment: Don't use sleep. Look into NSTimer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typewriter effect text animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736360/typewriter-effect-text-animation)

Comment: See my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See my code :**

In your `.h file` : define array of string.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *aryAll;
```

In your `.m file` .

```
@synthesize aryAll;
```

In `btnstart`

```
 - (IBAction)btnstart:(id)sender {

        self.aryAll = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        NSString *stringAnimation = @"My name is kirit modi come from deesa city";

        aryAll = [stringAnimation componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
                       ^{
                           [self animationString];
                       });

  }
```

**Method for animation :**

```
-(void)animationString
{
    for (int i =0; i< aryAll.count; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           [labnanme setText:[aryAll objectAtIndex:i]];
                       });

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    }
}
```

**You output is:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this ,declare readerArray and i as global

```
NSArray *readerArray;
  int i;

  - (IBAction)btnstart:(id)sender
 {

NSString *myString=self.textcollector.text;

   readerArray=[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

   NSUInteger arraylenght=[readerArray count];

    self.statuslabel.text=@"";

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)showText
{

    if (i<[readerArray count])
    {
        self.textcollector.text=readerArray[i];
        i++;

    }
}
```

invalidate the timer at last

Comment: "declare readerArray and i as global" – ***NO GOD,*** please don't. There's simply no need nor justification for that.