# Writing effect for UILabel text (iOS objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to give a effect for UILabel text that will look exactly same like we are writing on a paper using pen. I searched for it but not getting any related suggestion/solutions, there are solutions like typing effect but not as I need.

Comment: You can't do this with a normal UILabel, you'll have to draw this using some graphics API (OpenGL, Core Graphics, etc)... unless you just mean add a cursive font?

Comment: you want to display character one by one in label with animation.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel

Comment: @Kirti and sschunara: You are talking about type writer like effect but I need effect like writing text just like we view when writing on a paper by using a pen.

Comment: @Dig I repeat that the only way to accomplish this is to manually draw the stroked for the inserted letters via a graphics API (Core Graphics, OpenGL, etc.). You cannot accomplish this without manual drawing. It is possible that there's a 3rd party library that can help you with this.

Comment: You can use a tool like PaintCode to extract the bezier paths and what not to help you manually drag glyphs for each letter in an alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is to manually draw the stroked for the inserted letters via a graphics API (Core Graphics, OpenGL, etc.). You cannot accomplish this without manual drawing. It is possible that there's a 3rd party library that can help you with this. You can use a tool like [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) to extract the bezier paths and what not to help you manually drag glyphs for each letter in an alphabet and then animate those paths using Core Animation or another graphical drawing mechanism.