# Typing effect with attributed string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I found this code to animate a label with a typing effect. I'm trying to adapt it for attributed strings.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11687530/1813525

I tried this but I assume that i'm just recreating the same code based on the string of an attributed string :

```
- (void)animateLabelShowText:(NSAttributedString*)newText characterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    [self.mainLabel setText:@""];

    for (int i=0; i<newText.length; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
        [self.mainLabel setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%C", [self.mainLabel.attributedText string], [[newText string] characterAtIndex:i]] attributes:nil]];
                       });



        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could preserve the formatting of my attributed text `newText`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: it doesnt keep the formating of my attributed text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues (assuming you call `animateLabelShowText:characterDelay:` on a background thread).

1. You call `setText:@""` on the background thread. Don't do that.
2. You are building each new attributed string incorrectly.

Try this:

```
- (void)animateLabelShowText:(NSAttributedString*)newText characterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= newText.length; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSAttributedString *str = [newText attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, i)];
            self.mainLabel.attributedText = str;
        });

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept an answer that solves your issue.