# Animate text inside label - New word appears as if reading

Tags: swift, animation, label

I would like to animate my label, so that the words appear one by one every second.  Its as if the user is reading as the new words appear.
Does anyone know how to do this, or is there something on GitHub?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel

Comment: It's generally disapproved of to ask questions without trying something yourself and posting what you've tried. I've given an answer ('cos it's really quite easy), but next time, *try it yourself first* - few folk have time on their hands to write code for you!

Comment: Hi Grimxn, yeah you're completely right.  I'm quite new to coding and I am getting bit lazy.  Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SeyyedParsaNeshaei says, there is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel) that gives a "marquee" type scrolling, however, if what you want (as you say) is one word at a time, consider the following little sketch, which will run in Playground. It basically sets up a timer that changes the text of a `UILabel` one word at a time.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class MyVC: UIViewController {
    var tickTock: Int = 0
    var myString = ""
    var label: UILabel!
    // Following block only needed in Playground. 
    // Normally you would wire up the label in IB.
    { didSet { self.view.addSubview(self.label) } }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // This next line only necessary in Playground. 
        // Normally, the view would be set from the StoryBoard
        self.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 60)))
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // "1" in the next line is the inter-word interval in seconds.
        // Obviously you wouldn't hard-wire this.
        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            let words = self.myString.components(separatedBy: " ")
            var word = "<Nothing>"
            if words.count > 0 {
                self.tickTock = self.tickTock % words.count
                if !words[self.tickTock].isEmpty {
                    word = words[self.tickTock]
                }
            }
            self.label?.text = word
            self.tickTock += 1
        })
    }
}
// Playground code to test:
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60))
label.textColor = .yellow
label.textAlignment = .center
let myVC = MyVC()
myVC.myString = "May the source be with you"
myVC.label = label

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myVC.view
```

To see the animation, select "View>Assistant Editor>Show Assistant Editor" from the Playground menu.

For a fuller solution, you probably want to look at `components(separatedBy: CharactersSet)` rather than `components(separatedBy: String)`, which I've used - it depends on how you want to present punctuation...

Comment: Thanks again, works very well.  I was hoping to have the words remain so that at end would read the entire String ("May the source be with you").  Will have a play around, cheers again.

Comment: You're welcome! Easy to do - just display every word up to `tickTock` rather than the one at that index...

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it to work!  Quite pleased with myself and this make alot of sense now.  I was going to ask about invalidating the timer but I see you put a comment saying   // Obviously you wouldn't hard-wire this.  I think this answers my question...  Cheers!