# String letter by letter animation get mixed up when retrieving the next text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a pop up that is supposed to show the user instructions with letter by letter animation. The problem is whenever the user clicks "next" the letters get mixed up with the previous text.

The animation code:

```
extension UILabel {
    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = ""

            for (index, character) in newText.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The button action/calling method (as you can see I tried to empty the variable each time the user clicks "next" but it didn't work out)

```
@IBAction func nextbtt(_ sender: Any) {
    var instructions = ["text"]
    counter = counter + 1
    var w1 = " لكن الوصول إليه يتطلب مواجهة وحل تحديات مختلفة"
    var w2 = "هل بإمكانك مساعدتي  في الحصول على الكنز؟"

    let userId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userId") as? String
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    let  userLang = ref.child("users").child(userId!).child("lang")
    userLang.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let lang = snapshot.value as? Int
        if(lang==1){
            ////////////// if user's langague is English
             w1 = "But finding it requires confronting and solving different challenges"
             w2 = " Could you help me in getting the treasure"            }

        instructions.append(w1)
        instructions.append(w2)

        if(self.intrCounter < 3){
            self.mytext.text = ""

            var new = instructions[self.intrCounter]

            self.mytext.text = new

            self.mytext.animate(newText: new ?? "May the source be with you", characterDelay: 0.1)
            self.intrCounter = self.intrCounter + 1

            if(self.intrCounter == 3){
                if(lang==1){
                    (sender as AnyObject).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "engready"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                }
                else {
                    (sender as AnyObject).setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ready"), for: UIControl.State.normal)}
            }
        }
        else{
        }
    })

    if ( counter == 4){
        status[0] = true
        popUp.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

one: [text is showing to the user, user clicks "next" at the middle of the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKY0L.png)

two: [when user clicks next before text 1 is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjdOc.png)
Code:

Comment: You are trying to add the characters one by one right?

Comment: I want to display the text to the user one by one. I got the animation code from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because you are calling an asynchronous block for each character and probably each char takes another amount of time.
Just to test this try this change, if it will help change the code accordingly :

```
var someCounter = 1

extension UILabel {
    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = ""

            for (index, character) in newText.enumerated() {
                someCounter += 1
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 
                someCounter + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this is indeed the issue, if so I will upload a more optimised code.